# Send GET request to HTTPS with Basic Authentification parameters

Tags: php, javascript, html, applet, basic-authentication

My goal is, to establish an active connection between my `php` page and another page. There is a `java applet` located on my page, after some clicks, the applet will redirect my page to another. By default there is a login screen, but I want to skip that step, so when my applet redirects the page, i want, that the user will be logged in with my deafult login account.

I tried `"https://name:pass@addres"`, also tried some examples that i found after searching on the internet, but i still have no results

Comment: what means no result? what message do you get from the server when going to `https://name:pass@address`?

Comment: It's very difficult to do this in a smooth, cross-browser way with HTTP authentication. If you use e.g. a cookie auth system, or some other mechanism that uses a standard HTML form submission for logins, you can (I assume) use the Java applet to submit the form instead of performing a redirect.

Comment: if I type https://name:pass@address, browser redirects to login screen https://address

Comment: @user1463069 Yes, that is the browser doing that for you. The point is, when you do that does it log you in and bypass the login screen or not?

Comment: no, after that I get to the login screen with empty login fields

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers don't support that syntax any more due to security concerns.

Mostly because of un-encoded passwords plus the possibility to create fake URLs that look something like this:

http://www.yourbank.com_somelongpath:xxx@somescammerssite.com

99% of internet users will believe that's an URL belonging to "yourbank.com" and not "somescammerssite.com".